# Why react is not calling componentDidMount function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on reactJs project and using react redux for login and user load but am facing issue that if even auth.user is loaded sucessfully and I am redirected from login page to home page componentDidMount function is not printing 'hiii' on console.

if then I go to another page and then return on Home page then it is printing value on console. Why it is not printing value first time when I am redirected to home page after successfull login(auth.user) is loaded.
How is it possible to get that at first time.

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
        }     
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.auth.user) (
            console.log('hiii')) 
      }
    render() {
      return(
         <div>
         </div>
    </div>
    )}
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(Home);
```

Comment: You had check `this.props.auth.user` in `componentDidMount` method and then `console.log('hiii')`. If `this.props.auth.user` value is available so `console.log('hiii')` render. Initial render `this.props.auth.user` value might be null so after `API` call store data in redux and it's shown.

Comment: React is almost certainly calling `componentDidMount()` as normal, it's just that `this.props.auth.user` is falsy for whatever reason the first time it mounts.

Comment: Log something before the condition if(this.props.auth.user) to see if the Home component is at least mounted correctly without any errors. Because I can already see that you have a <div></div></div>. -_-

Comment: @Asifvora I tried this. if I print something before if condition on console. that thing is printing successfully. I think the auth. user is loaded after some seconds so it is not printing 'hiii' first time. is there a way to wait for user load into store and than

Comment: Yes, coz `componentDidMount ` called only once.

Comment: you can try with `componentWillReceiveProps` method https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops